# How do I unexpand a file name?

Tags: filenames

Given `~/foo/bar`, I can get `/home/sds/foo/bar` using [`expand-file-name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Expansion.html).

However, given `/Users/sds/foo/bar`, how do I get `~/foo/bar`?

Use case: I want to copy a file between computers and they have different physical paths to my home directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use function `abbreviate-file-name`.  `C-h f` says:

```
abbreviate-file-name is a compiled Lisp function in `files.el'.

(abbreviate-file-name FILENAME)

Return a version of FILENAME shortened using `directory-abbrev-alist`.
This also substitutes "~" for the user's home directory (unless the
home directory is a root directory) and removes automounter prefixes
(see the variable `automount-dir-prefix`).
```

See also the Elisp manual, node [Directory Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Names.html).